# Vibrating motors with different intervals

Tags: programming, motor

For my project, I have 3 ultrasonic sensors and 3 vibrating motors; the motors need to buzz for a small amount of time, then wait for a specific time that corresponds whith the range of the ultrasonic sensor, then muzz again.

The problem I'm having is that I used delays at first but that would cause the third motor only to buzz after the first two already waited.

I basically need something like "digitalWrite(motorPin_1, HIGH) for X amount of time;"
and at the same moment it has to start "digitalWrite(motorPin_2, HIGH) for X amount of time;".

Sadly I can't get the motors to vibrate any softer or harder, so I use these intervals.

Comment: Did you check the [Blink Without Delay](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino tutorial?

Comment: oh, thanks i had no idea it was so simple. with the blink it works just as i wanted! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Edgar commented, you need to check out Blink Without Delay (http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay). Learn what they are doing and you will get this just fine.

Also, I recommend you learn to use libraries. This library can do exactly what you are asking for: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LibraryList#Timing --> click on the "Timer" library by Simon Monk & J Christensen. Follow the examples there. This library works great!

Here is a complete set of code to answer your question. It should work perfectly for you.

```
/*
buzz3Motors.ino
By Gabriel Staples
http://electricrcaircraftguy.blogspot.com/
7 March 2015

To help this person here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9089/vibriting-motors-with-different-intervals
*/

#include "Timer.h"

Timer t;

boolean buzzMotor1Now = false, buzzMotor2Now = false, buzzMotor3Now = false;
unsigned int buzzTime = 1000; //ms
byte buzzPin1 = 11;
byte buzzPin2 = 12;
byte buzzPin3 = 13;

void setup()
{
  //set pins to outputs
  pinMode(buzzPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzPin3, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  //UPDATE YOUR BUZZMOTOR BOOLEANS HERE, and set to true if necessary


  /**
   * This method will generate a pulse of pulseValue, starting immediately and of
   * length period. The pin will be left in the !pulseValue state
   */
  //Function format: int8_t pulseImmediate(uint8_t pin, unsigned long period, uint8_t pulseValue);
  //see here: https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer/blob/master/Timer.h

  if (buzzMotor1Now==true)
  {
    buzzMotor1Now = false; //reset
    t.pulseImmediate(buzzPin1,buzzTime,HIGH);
  }
  if (buzzMotor2Now==true)
  {
    buzzMotor2Now = false; //reset
    t.pulseImmediate(buzzPin2,buzzTime,HIGH);
  }
  if (buzzMotor3Now==true)
  {
    buzzMotor3Now = false; //reset
    t.pulseImmediate(buzzPin3,buzzTime,HIGH);
  }

  t.update(); //update all timer events
}
```

Note that only 10 timer events can be ongoing at any given time. If you want to have more you must increase the MAX_NUMBER_OF_EVENTS value in the Timer.h (https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer/blob/master/Timer.h) file.

PS. Also look into the "oscillate", "after", "every", and "pulse" functions, that the library also supports.

**If this answer meets your needs please mark the green check beside it to indicate accepted answer. Thanks.**

Comment: you are completely right, the timer library works great, thanks for your replie. :p